# How to get elements on dynamic pages when the element is available when page scrolls down?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to we scraping Instagram posts with Python and Selenium but I only get the first 23 posts since they load up to where the page scrolls and for more posts, the page need to scroll down more so more posts get loaded to the page.

Any idea of how to get all the posts of a page and then iterate through them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to control scroll system using `execute_script`

Step 1:

```
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

Step 2:

```
# Scroll down to bottom
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Final Step:

```
#Find out if you reached the end of the page
new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
if new_height == last_height:
    break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: I am not sure its working. Please correct me if I am wrong. 
1. It wont even compile. It complains about the break.
2. It scroll down up just to the size of the scroll bar. it wont auto load content .

Comment: I have an Instagram bot and I made this code to scroll down, get post links and download pics. My process was 1.- Open ig profile, collect the first 24 post links (I used list var), scroll down and again collect 24 post links, until Step 3 is executed. Then I eliminated duplicated posts and started another process to visit each link and download images. I could share my code but it might get confuse because was made according my needs.

Comment: Thats great. can you please share the part of your code that you just mentioned ?

Comment: I just made a special version of my class for you... Check out the link below. Run it in your terminal and let me know your thoughts. https://trinket.io/python/d296c10f03

Comment: Thank you. I am going to give it a try and let you know.